# Ransack issue: default sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, ransack

I have the next two models:

```
class Game
  belongs_to :tournament, inverse_of: :games

  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Tournament
  has_many :games, dependent: :destroy

  validates_numericality_of :number
end
```

So, I have a **list of games that shows their tournament's number**, and I want as a default to order the list by the tournament's number.

In my controller I have something like this:

```
@q = Game.search(params[:q])
@q.sorts = 'tournaments_number' if q.sorts.blank?
@q = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
```

The problem is it is not ordering the list by the number. Take a look at the query

```
    @q = Game.search(params[:q])
    @q.sorts = 'tournaments_number' if q.sorts.blank?
    puts @q.result.to_sql # => SELECT * FROM games
    @q = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
```

But if I order by a field of games, it works great:

```
    @q = Game.search(params[:q])
    @q.sorts = 'name' if q.sorts.blank?
    puts @q.result.to_sql # => SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY name
    @q = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? How can I be able to sort by the associated attribute?

**EDIT:**

I've found out that if I do the next, the order works:

```
    @q = Game.includes(:tournament).order('tournaments.number').search(params[:q])
    puts @q.result.to_sql # => SELECT * FROM games INNER JOIN tournaments ON games.tournament_id = tournaments.id ORDER BY tournaments.number
    @q = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
```

The problem is that, although I can add some conditional, I need to make it work with ransack, given that I use a sort_link in other place, and it is not working.

```
<%= sort_link(@q, 'tournaments.number') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do this:

```
@q = Game.search(params[:q])
@q.sorts = 'tournaments.number' if q.sorts.blank?
@q = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: I've edited the post for adding more information. Take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be if @q.sorts.blank?